# Grabbing value of a Dynamic Element inside a Frame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, frames, frameset

I've been struggling with this for a few days now, I was hoping I could find some help here!

I have a simple html page which has two frames. The frameset looks like :

```
<frameset rows=15%,*>
<frame src="frTop.html" name="frTop">
<frame src="frBot.html" name="frBot">
</frameset>
```

The frame "frTop" has a textbox and a button. When you input a value in that box and hit the button, it loads a URL into the frame "frBot".

The page that loads has some values in it, and one of them is a dynamic value (It doesn't change unless you manually change it in the page).

What I want to do is to load the URL, and pull that dynamic value into a variable/textbox/something that I can manipulate.

The idea being, I want to specify 100-200 values, visit each of those URLs, grab the value, and store it into a spreadsheet.

My biggest problem is that the URL being loaded is an external link, ie : I am not able to access the elements of that page using the getElementById("") command. (My knowledge of HTML is limited, so I am not sure if this approach would work or not).

Additional Info :
The dynamic element I want has the following segment of code in the HTML of the external page.

```
<span class="status"></span>
```

Thanks in Advance,
Sai

Answer (score 0):

I almost never use `iframes`, so I may be wrong here, but I believe you cannot manipulate the DOM of the document in an `iframe` if the source is from an external site due to some security reasons.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you are referring to *html sniffing* in that you perform a deep dive on an externally fetched site to search through their html for some specific piece of information.

This would require a language that allows you to make an http request, read in the file, and parse through it for what you want.  This can be a standalone application written in C#, Java, etc.  or even a server-side script such as PHP, ASP, etc.

Setting up such an application is beyond the scope of this answer, though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful reply! And yeah, that is what I expected.

Is there any other way to achieve the same effect? I am currently trying to work with AutoIt to simulate some onscreen effects, not sure how effective they would be, though.